# filter subdocuments array with mongoose using find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 2 schemas:

```
const SiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    placement: Number,
    groupId: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

and

```
const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    placement: Number,
    header: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    items: [Site.schema],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

I'm trying to get all groups with up to 5 of their corresponding sites based on the sites placement value like this:

```
roup.find({ 'items.placement': { $lte: 5 } })
      .skip(offset)
      .limit(maxNumberOfResults)
      .sort('placement')
      .lean()
      .then(groups => {res.send({ sites: groups}))
```

however the result i get is all the sites in the group, regardless of their placement value.

for example:
I'm expecting to get:

```
      [
        {
            "_id": "60dd2c314d98940d90fe8861",
            "placement": 0,
            "createdAt": "some date",
            "updatedAt": "some date",
            "header": "group",
            "items": [
                {
                    "_id": "60dd2cb54d98940d90fefb2a",
                    "groupId": "60dd2c314d98940d90fe8861",
                    "placement": 1,
                    "title": "something",
                    "url": "some url",
                    "createdAt": "some date",
                    "updatedAt": "some date"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60dd2cb54d98940d90fefb2d",
                    "groupId": "60dd2c314d98940d90fe8861",
                    "placement": 2,
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60dd2cb54d98940d90fefb2f",
                    "groupId": "60dd2c314d98940d90fe8861",
                    "placement": 3,
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60dd2cb54d98940d90fefb30",
                    "groupId": "60dd2c314d98940d90fe8861",
                    "placement": 4,
                },{
                    "_id": "60dd2cb54d98940d90fefb30",
                    "groupId": "60dd2c314d98940d90fe8861",
                    "placement": 5,
                },
              ]
```

but getting placements 6 and onwards as well

***If someone could also tell me how to sort the subdocument array according to the placement value, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `items: [Site.schema]` to `items: [SiteSchema],`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't have any effect